# exec rm -rf not working to delete a .sql file in php

Tags: php, windows, codeigniter

I am using CI3 and I am using exec() to delete a sql file. I used the following code to delete my .sql file

```
exec("rm -rf C:/xampp/htdocs/helloword/temp/test1.sql");
```

It is not deleting the file and when I use **2>&1** it says

```
operable program or batch file.
```

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: On Windows there is no `rm`, just `cmd /c del /s`.

Comment: It would be better by deleting the file using PHP's builtin functions like [unlink](http://php.net/manual/es/function.unlink.php) ,your code will be more portable and less error prone.

Comment: thanks MrTux. is there any script available where windows and linux both support same script

Comment: Thank you Daniel..I used unlink and it worked..thanks again